# Does anyone know why I'm getting a completely black geotiff as a result of this shapefile cut out of another geotiff in rasterio?

Tags: python, shapefile, geotiff-tiff, masking, rasterio

I am using rasterio to cut out the shape of a lake outlined in my shapefile from a geotiff. When using a shapefile of a singular lake with a geotiff, this works perfectly, but not when cutting out a geotiff of a single lake with a different shapefile that contains a lot of different lake outlines. I'm wondering if there is a problem with the way my code is written or the files I'm using?

Here's my code:

```
import rasterio
import rasterio.mask
import fiona

with fiona.open("liag_shapes/liag_shapes.shp", "r") as shapefile:
    features = [feature["geometry"]for feature in shapefile]

with rasterio.open("lakesimcoe11.tif") as src:
    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, features, 
filled=True, crop=True)
    out_meta = src.meta.copy()

out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
             "height": out_image.shape[1],
             "width": out_image.shape[2],
             "transform": out_transform})

with rasterio.open("new_test.tif", "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(out_image)
```

Comment: In my experience an all black output is often indicative mismatched NoData values. Have you tried plotting `out_image` before you write it to see what it looks like? Also check the minimum value of `out_image` and see if it makes sense. I don't see any obvious issues with your code.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that, hopefully will at least give me a better idea of what's going on.